# Parse natural/humain dates using a reference date

Tags: python, datetime

To parse string date in natural language to python datetime , I am using [parsedattime module](https://code.google.com/p/parsedatetime/).

```
   from parsedatetime import parsedatetime as pdt
   from parsedatetime import parsedatetime_consts as pdc
   from datetime import datetime

   str_date = '5minutes ago'
   c = pdc.Constants()
   p = pdt.Calendar(c)
   struct_date = p.parse(str_date)[0]
   ## format the result
   dt = datetime.fromtimestamp(mktime(struct_date))
   print dt.isoformat()
```

This will works well but the result changes in each execution , since it is :

```
  NOW() - '5minutes ago'
```

How should I modify this to parse `5minutes ago` using a reference date to get always the same result and parse internally something like :

```
  REF_DATE - '5minutes ago'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Provide the [`sourceTime` attribute](https://github.com/bear/parsedatetime/blob/d7304f18f7bf8f69c8e228d641d80c649810ab95/parsedatetime/__init__.py#L1280).

```
p.parse(str_date, sourceTime=datetime(year=2000, month=1, day=1))
```